# zoom background image but not text in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to background image to be zoom on page but not text over it.

CSS:

```
.page1-box {
    width: 1200px;
    height:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.page1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../images/home_page.jpg');
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    transform:scale(1);
    transition:all 5s ease-in;
}
.page1.zout {
    transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Js code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.pag1').addClass('zout');
}, 100);
```

HTML Code:

```
<section class="page1">
     <div class="page_container">
        <div class="text">
            sample text here
        </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

If I run this code `sample text here` will get transform to zoom which I don't want. Is there any solution to zoom background image only not text over it?

Please help.

Comment: Change the `background-size` value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various tricks to get this zooming effect. Here are two:

**One: with help of background image:**

```
 <div class="page-bg"></div>
```

Call an empty div inside your section element and set background image for that declaring height and width. But this is not semantic way of markup. Though give it a try:

```
.page-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B6mjgHuCIAEgyli.jpg');
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    transform:scale(1);
    transition:all 5s ease-in;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/getanwar/pggbkws6/) for your effect.

**Trick Two:** Semantic way. instead of calling images from CSS as a background image, directly call it in your HTML markup and position with parent element via CSS. Thus, you will have a flexible area to play with.

```
<div class="page1-box">
    <section class="page1">
        <img src="../images/bg-img.jpg" alt="bg">
        <div class="page_container">
            <div class="text">sample text here</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS for this trick is quite similar to first one that's why I am not going to show here. Play it with. If this does not solve your issue don't forget to comment below. :)

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions:

**'Zoom' your background image using `background-size`:**

```
.page1.zout {
     background-size: [VALUE];
}
```

Play about with 'Value' until it gives you the size you're after.

**Bring the text outside of the transformed element:**

```
<section class="page1">
     <div class="page_container">
     </div>
 </section>

 <div class="text">
      sample text here
  </div>
```

Now the transform won't be applied to `text`, but you must now position `text` as a result as it won't sit inside the page in the same way.

If bringing `text` outside of the `section` element means your DOM is now, semantically, incorrect - consider creating an element with the 'zoomed' background further inside:

```
<section class="page1">
     <div class="background-to-transform">
     </div>
     <div class="text">
         sample text here
     </div>
 </section>
```